# How to implement Google maps in android without Google play service?

Tags: android, google-maps, blackberry, apk, google-play-services

I have implemented Google maps in my android application using Google play service and it is working fine.I have tried the same APK installed with **Blackberry**,so all the things working fine but maps not working.The problem is **Google play service is not available in Blackberry**. So if some device not support Google play service, I have to go for an alternative solution.
I search lot but could not find proper solution.

```
if(isGooglePlayServiceAvilable){
 //implement maps with GooglePlayService(I did this part)
}else{
 //Please suggest me an alternative solution for this.( :( )
}
```

Comment: all the class have in google play service so how can u do without play service

Comment: @Dinesh Anuruddha did You solve it?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I will use 
- ImageView to display the google static map instead. 
- Add some on screen message to notify user about the cripple functionality of missing Play Services. 
- Add OnClick on the static map ImageView to open google map (web) with Intent

^^